# Live boot GUI convert a primary partition to a logical partition?

Tags: partition, gparted

Is Gparted Live unable to convert a primary partition to a logical partition?
i.e. to make an extended partition and make that primary partition a logical partition within the newly created extended partition?  (or to move a primary partition to an existing extended partition)

What GUI alternative is there to Gparted Live that can?

I don't see any option here e.g. in the partition menu, for converting a primary to a logical.

[image]

Comment: Try to do that with 'sfdisk'. But extended partition itself needs some bytes. Make backup!

Comment: related http://www.acronis.com/en-gb/personal/disk-manager/

Comment: WinPE liek BartPE would run whatever full version of windows software.. or booting linux eg ubuntu off usb and whatever linux software

Answer (score -1):

EaseUS Partition Master can convert primary partitions to logical. http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

It runs on Windows but I see you have a Windows partition anyway.

EDIT: From your graphic it seems you're not maxing out the number of partitions so if you have enough space you can resize, make a new extended logical partition and copy the partition data across. If you maxed out on 4 primaries or not enough space, back up your partition, delete it, then make a new extended logical partition and restore your data into a logical partition.

Comment: -1   I said Live..  And you just said it runs on windows.  If easeus had a bootable version that was free then fine, but then you should say that.  I could also add a criteria of free, but  to state something that's not live, just doesn't meet the criteria.  I did know about easeus, I think maybe it may have a bootable version but not free.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the live criteria because it wasn't worded intuitively. 
EaseUS PM can do live USB, but seems you have to pay for it though you can always use the free trial (please edit your original question to include free criteria as well) http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/usb-bootable-disk.htm

Comment: My question didn't specify free, though of course if you know of a free one that does it then it's even better.  And have you tested the paid bootable usb version whether it can convert the partition?  (btw I wrote Live many times including even in the first word of the subject and the first sentence of the body).   If you could show a screenshot of the option in the bootable usb version then that'd be something